# How to get device serialno without ask runtime permission READ_PHONE_STATE in Android O

Tags: java, android, permissions, java-native-interface, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to get the serial number of the device on Android O, I have looked around and found:

```
 1. Build.SERIAL is deprecated so we have to use Build.getSerial();
 2. ro.serialno is no more accessible: "Access denied finding property "ro.serialno""
```

As regards the first approach my problem is that it requires the `READ_PHONE_STATE` and it must be asked at runtime. I need a way to do it without impact user experience any idea on how to do it?

Is it possible?

Comment: Hopefully, that is not possible. The point behind locking these things down is to prevent apps from getting unique identifiers silently, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Of course silent is not the right word I edit the question, the main problem is the user experience. By the way it was possible in android < 26.

Comment: "the main problem is the user experience" -- asking for permission should not be a user experience problem. Lots of apps ask users for runtime permissions, so your users should be familiar with the process. "it was possible in android < 26" -- Google is continuously tightening things down to help reduce privacy risks in using Android apps.

Comment: I got your point, but the problem is that if you have to sell your own solution to a client and he has to integrate it in its own application having popup from your side is not appreciated.

Comment: Then tell the client to request the runtime permission, sometime before you need it. Have your own runtime permission check as a failsafe, but put the responsibility on the client to handle the permission request at a time and fashion that the client deems to be appropriate. There is a very good chance that your client's app already requests runtime permissions for other things, and so this will not be a big shock to them.

Answer (score 0):

The value is deprecated, not hidden; and even this, only for apps with `targetSdkVersion 26` and higher. Which means that you can still use it without runtime permissions if you target Android N. Furthermore, if you use `targetSdkVersion 23` or less, you can request `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission without popups. And then, when the app upgrades to target Oreo, the system will already have the permission granted to this app_id.

This said, I must confess that we had been worried about the runtime permission popups until we were forced to push `targetSdkVersion` to `24`, but our concerns proved to be baseless. We don't experience significant changes in usage patterns.

Finally, I would also recommend not to rely on `Build.SERIAL`. As a remote fingerprint, [adid](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient) is quite adequate; in situations when your fingerprint must survive udid reset, `Build.SERIAL` does provide protection with rooted device or cracked APK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I have read about it, but currently the behaviour seems to be a little bit different in examples in my gradle I have    `compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25

    }` .    if I try to access to getserial if we are in Android O the application crashes due to missing permission, if I had the popup request all works and I was wondering why.

Comment: Correct, [Build.getSerial()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#getSerial()) does require permissions. But for `targetSdkVersion 25` you [can](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/changes-to-device-identifiers-in.html) use Build.SERIAL.